# PHPExcel. Create chart that allows save it where i want

Tags: phpexcel

I am trying to combine two examples. [eg1](https://github.com/cystbear/PHPExcel/blob/master/Tests/01simple-download-xlsx.php) and [eg2](https://github.com/MrRoyce/obgyn/blob/master/Tests/33chartcreate-column.php) runs fine independently.
I would like to create a chart from php but allows me to save it where I want. But when I try to open always tells me it's corrupt or extension is not correct.
I have looked some answers to similar questions and have not been able to find appropriate solution.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally i did it.
Now the problem is, i can't rename the worksheet where i save the graph. 
If i do that, Excel can't open the file.

The code:

```
<?php

/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

define('EOL',(PHP_SAPI == 'cli') ? PHP_EOL : '<br />');

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

/** PHPExcel */
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../Classes/PHPExcel.php';


$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$objWorksheet->fromArray(
    array(
        array('',   2010,   2011,   2012),
        array('Q1',   12,   15,     21),
        array('Q2',   56,   73,     86),
        array('Q3',   52,   61,     69),
        array('Q4',   30,   32,     0),
    )
);

$dataseriesLabels = array(
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$B$1', NULL, 1),   //  2010
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$C$1', NULL, 1),   //  2011
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$D$1', NULL, 1),   //  2012
);

$xAxisTickValues = array(
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$A$2:$A$5', NULL, 4),  //  Q1 to Q4
);

$dataSeriesValues = array(
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Worksheet!$B$2:$B$5', NULL, 4),
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Worksheet!$C$2:$C$5', NULL, 4),
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Worksheet!$D$2:$D$5', NULL, 4),
);

//  Build the dataseries
$series = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries(
    PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::TYPE_BARCHART,       // plotType
    PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::GROUPING_STANDARD,   // plotGrouping
    range(0, count($dataSeriesValues)-1),           // plotOrder
    $dataseriesLabels,                              // plotLabel
    $xAxisTickValues,                               // plotCategory
    $dataSeriesValues                               // plotValues
);
//  Set additional dataseries parameters
//      Make it a vertical column rather than a horizontal bar graph
$series->setPlotDirection(PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::DIRECTION_COL);

//  Set the series in the plot area
$plotarea = new PHPExcel_Chart_PlotArea(NULL, array($series));
//  Set the chart legend
$legend = new PHPExcel_Chart_Legend(PHPExcel_Chart_Legend::POSITION_RIGHT, NULL, false);

$title = new PHPExcel_Chart_Title('Test Column Chart');
$yAxisLabel = new PHPExcel_Chart_Title('Value ($k)');

//  Create the chart
$chart = new PHPExcel_Chart(
    'chart1',       // name
    $title,         // title
    $legend,        // legend
    $plotarea,      // plotArea
    true,           // plotVisibleOnly
    0,              // displayBlanksAs
    NULL,           // xAxisLabel
    $yAxisLabel     // yAxisLabel
);

//  Set the position where the chart should appear in the worksheet
$chart->setTopLeftPosition('A7');
$chart->setBottomRightPosition('H20');

//  Add the chart to the worksheet
$objWorksheet->addChart($chart);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Probando');

// Save Excel 2007 file
// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel2007)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');


$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```

The line "$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Probando');" is the problem, some idea?

PS: Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

@koky 
Rename the sheet first, and then create the table and graph, like so:

```
<?php

/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

define('EOL',(PHP_SAPI == 'cli') ? PHP_EOL : '<br />');

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

/** PHPExcel */
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Classes/PHPExcel.php';


$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Probando');
$objWorksheet->fromArray(
    array(
        array('',   2010,   2011,   2012),
        array('Q1',   12,   15,     21),
        array('Q2',   56,   73,     86),
        array('Q3',   52,   61,     69),
        array('Q4',   30,   32,     0),
    )
);

$dataseriesLabels = array(
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Probando!$B$1', NULL, 1),   //  2010
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Probando!$C$1', NULL, 1),   //  2011
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Probando!$D$1', NULL, 1),   //  2012
);

$xAxisTickValues = array(
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Probando!$A$2:$A$5', NULL, 4),  //  Q1 to Q4
);

$dataSeriesValues = array(
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Probando!$B$2:$B$5', NULL, 4),
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Probando!$C$2:$C$5', NULL, 4),
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Probando!$D$2:$D$5', NULL, 4),
);

//  Build the dataseries
$series = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries(
    PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::TYPE_BARCHART,       // plotType
    PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::GROUPING_STANDARD,   // plotGrouping
    range(0, count($dataSeriesValues)-1),           // plotOrder
    $dataseriesLabels,                              // plotLabel
    $xAxisTickValues,                               // plotCategory
    $dataSeriesValues                               // plotValues
);
//  Set additional dataseries parameters
//      Make it a vertical column rather than a horizontal bar graph
$series->setPlotDirection(PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::DIRECTION_COL);

//  Set the series in the plot area
$plotarea = new PHPExcel_Chart_PlotArea(NULL, array($series));
//  Set the chart legend
$legend = new PHPExcel_Chart_Legend(PHPExcel_Chart_Legend::POSITION_RIGHT, NULL, false);

$title = new PHPExcel_Chart_Title('Test Column Chart');
$yAxisLabel = new PHPExcel_Chart_Title('Value ($k)');

//  Create the chart
$chart = new PHPExcel_Chart(
    'chart1',       // name
    $title,         // title
    $legend,        // legend
    $plotarea,      // plotArea
    true,           // plotVisibleOnly
    0,              // displayBlanksAs
    NULL,           // xAxisLabel
    $yAxisLabel     // yAxisLabel
);

//  Set the position where the chart should appear in the worksheet
$chart->setTopLeftPosition('A7');
$chart->setBottomRightPosition('H20');

//  Add the chart to the worksheet
$objWorksheet->addChart($chart);

// Save Excel 2007 file
// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel2007)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');


$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
?>
```

Comment: This is really a comment/answer to another answer.  You need to add a @koky (in this case) for that user to see it.